# Using PHP to display random line of CSV by column

Tags: php, csv, random

I want to pick a random line out of a CSV file and display it, while also being able to add style through css/html. Ideally I could set each key (of the randomly chosen row) to display separately (as to be styled).

Activity, description, step 1, step 2, step 3, comments

could display as

**Activity** 
*Description*
- step 1 
- step 2 
- step 3 
**comments**

I've been using the following code, but i cant break the values out to style them separately.

```
<? 

$sep=","; // separator 
$mycsv=file("hopper-01.csv"); 
$row=rand(0,count($mycsv)-1); 
$data=explode($sep,$mycsv[$row]); 

$num = count ($data); 

for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) { 
  print $data[$c] . "<br>"; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: Use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) for working with CSV, for starters!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "break out" the values? It looks like you've already got your random row and and have put each column value into an array. Surely the rest would be HTML/CSS formatting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the structure of your CSV ahead of time (and it seems like you do).  In that case, you just have to style differently based on the key:

```
for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
   switch ($c) {
      case 0:
         echo "<strong>" . $data[$c] . "</strong><br>";
         break;
      case 1:
         echo "<em>" . $data[$c] . "</em><br>";
         break;
      case 2:
      case 3:
      case 4:
         echo "- " . $data[$c] . "<br>";
   }
}
```

...etc.

Comment: 2, 3, and 4 should presumably be LIs in an UL, not printed with literal `-`.

Comment: @Barmar certainly a possibility

Answer (score 0):

```
   Try This code: 

   $newfilename="hopper-01.csv";
    $filename = fopen($newfilename,"r");
    $content="";

    $i=0;
    while(!feof($filename))
      {
    $content=fgetcsv($filename,100000,','); 
        if($content[0]!="")
          {
    echo $content[0];
    echo"<br>";
    echo $content[1];
    echo"<br>";
    echo $content[2];
    echo"<br>";
    echo $content[3];
    echo"<br>";
    echo $content[4];
    echo"<br>";
              }
      }

    fclose($filename);
```